# Two PNR, one itinerary - baggage allowance for Qatar Airways and American Airlines

Tags: luggage, american-airlines, qatar-airways

I have three flights (two connections) in my itinerary. The first two of them are Qatar Airways business class tickets, and they cover 95% of the entire journey. The last one is an American Airline (Operated by ENVOY AIR AS AMERICAN EAGLE), and it is an economy seat.

[Qatar Airways allows me](http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/baggage.page) to carry **two** checked in items while [American Airlines allows](http://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/baggage/baggageAllowance.jsp#charges) **only one**. This is what I've learnt from both these airlines' official websites.

**Even though everything is in one ticket/itinerary, there are two different PNRs - one for both Qatar Airways flights and another one for American Airlines flight.**

The ticket given by my online-travel-agent shows 2 pieces for all three flights individually, but this information is not shown when I enter my PNR in both Qatar and American Airlines' websites. Should I neglect that and carry my agent's ticket? It seems if things do go wrong, I might have to pay $100 for the 2nd piece.

> *NOTE:* The last flight, American Airlines, is from Chicago to Ohio,
>   hence it might count as a Domestic flight rather than an International
>   connection flight. This is one of my doubts about the whole thing.

Comment: It's not directly related to your question, but I've been on those small commuter planes quite a bit (ORD->Ohio): note that overhead space tends to be very limited - quite small bags only. Any larger bags will be "valet checked" or gate-checked. I find it convenient to limit the amount and size of carry-on bags I have.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier You are correct! This AA plane, being a small one, doesn't have much room for carry-ons. It is not a problem for me at all, since I am carrying an almost empty schoolbag (for passport and other docs). The main two-piece luggage I was talking about are travel bags way under the weight and size limits. If I merge them in to one, which is very possible, it might get quite uncomfortable to handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as it's all on one ticket, then as explained on [this Qatar airways page](http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/baggage-most-significant-carrier.page), the [most significant carrier's allowance applies](http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/baggage-most-significant-carrier.page)

Since the bulk of your journey is on Qatar airways, including at least one long international flight, the Qatar ticket's allowance of 2 bags will apply throughout

Additionally, since both airlines are part of One World, you'll be able to check your luggage through the whole way. Leaving America, you'll be able to check your bags at the starting airport, and not see them until after your final flight. Coming into America, you'll be able to get them tagged to the final location, but you'll need to collect them at your first American airport + clear customs with them + hand them to AA bag re-drop after customs to carry on to the final hop

Comment: @pnuts Could you please explain what those exception are? Does American Airlines not follow the MSC policy?

Comment: @pnuts The USA exception says it's the airline listed first on the ticket which'd apply, in this case it's Qatar again so no change