# Extra baggage (bicycle) rules on multi-operator itinerary

Tags: air-travel, luggage, bicycles

This question specifically applies to flying with bicycles. Some airlines (such as Etihad) are "bike-friendly" and allow inclusion of suitably packed bikes in the total allowance, others don't.

What happens on an international itinerary where the first leg is not operated by the issuing airline?

For instance a ticket issued by Etihad Airways has the following legs:

Houston - Dallas/Fort Worth: American Airlines
Dallas/Fort Worth - Abu Dhabi: Etihad
Abu Dhabi - New Delhi: Etihad

Even though Etihad is the [significant carrier](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40317/two-pnr-one-itinerary-baggage-allowance-for-qatar-airways-and-american-airlin) the passenger will check in at Houston with American Airlines.

Will American apply their baggage rules ($150 for the bike)?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you will not have to pay the extra fee. Assuming you booked your entire flight through Etihaad, they have partnership agreements with the first airline that will allow you to check the additional bags for free because they will be free on the international portion.

Comment: It woukd be wise to print a copy of Eithad's rules on bikes to show at DFW. Not every agent will be aware of their policies.